# Adding a floating number and I'm getting an error

Tags: python

I have tried to figure out what I did wrong but when I try the code different ways it gives an error or wrong result I'm looking for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

tax = 0.06

def sales_tax(total):
    sales_tax = total * tax
    return total


def main():
    print("Sales Tax Calculator\n")
    total = float(input("Enter total: "))
    total_after_tax =(total+sales_tax)
    print("Total after tax: ", total_after_tax)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

then I tired to do it like this but it just added the total + total.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

tax = 0.06

def sales_tax(total):
    sales_tax = total * tax
    return total


def main():
    print("Sales Tax Calculator\n")
    total = float(input("Enter total: "))
    total_after_tax =(total+sales_tax(total))
    print("Total after tax: ", total_after_tax)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated[error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfncP.png).

Comment: In your second code snippet `return sales_tax` instead of `return total`

Comment: The code in your image is different to the code in your post. In your image you have `total+sales_tax` which should be `total+sales_tax(total)`, the same as what you have in your post.

Comment: what is the goal of `sales_tax` function? You are returning `total` so basically you are not doing any operation on it. You should return: `sales_tax` and call the function as `total_after_tax =(total+sales_tax(total))`

Comment: @josh - please take a moment and mark your question as answered. If you were not provided an answer from a member, please answer your question or kindly delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tax = 0.06

def sales_tax(total):
    sales_tax = total * tax
    return sales_tax


def main():
    print("Sales Tax Calculator\n")
    total = float(input("Enter total: "))
    total_after_tax =(total+sales_tax(total))
    print("Total after tax: ", total_after_tax)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


try this code, it is working properly.
In your sales_tax function u are returning total instead of sales_tax
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code-block, you are setting `sales_tax = total * tax`, but then you just return the original `total`.  That means the value of `sales_tax(total)` will just be the original `total.`  If you return `total * tax` instead of `total`, then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
tax = 0.06

def sales_tax(total):
    return total*tax


def main():
    print("Sales Tax Calculator\n")
    total = float(input("Enter total: "))
    total_after_tax =(total+sales_tax(total))
    print("Total after tax: ", total_after_tax)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```